# Подсчитать количество значений в столбце i с одинаковым значением в столбце j

Tags: javascript, d3.js

есть массив данных, нужны два столбца: code и nutriscore продукта. значение в nutriscore- цифра {1,...,9}. для каждого nutriscore (от 1 до 9) надо посчитать количество продуктов (кол-во кодов в столбце code).

```
d3.tsv("products_only_breads.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var nutriscore = data['nutriscore']
  var product_amount=[]

nutriscore.forEach(function(a){
    product_amount[a] = product_amount[a] + 1 || 1;
});
for (var key in product_amount)
    document.write('число ' + key + ' == ' + product_amount[key] + ' раз(а) <br>');

  console.log(product_amount)
```

Comment: исходный массив та хоть покажите

Comment: не учебное задание ли часом??

Comment: довольно простое задание так то

Comment: а как массив выгглядит из мапить та результат вообще это как бы вот делать нада из условия что надо  от 1 до 9 `for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    result.push({
        nutriscore: i,
        count: Y.filter(v => v.nutriscore == i).length
    });
}`

Comment: var nutriscore = data['nutriscore']  результат присваивания покажите  в вопросе как он выглядит например вывядите в конесоль разверните сущности и скрин сделайте

Answer (score 2):

Гвозди микроскопом:

```js
let data = [{
    code: '123',
    nutriscore: 1
  },
  {
    code: '234',
    nutriscore: 1
  },
  {
    code: '345',
    nutriscore: 2
  },
  {
    code: '456',
    nutriscore: 2
  },
  {
    code: '567',
    nutriscore: 3
  },
  {
    code: '678',
    nutriscore: 2
  },
];
let db = new SQL.Database();
db.run('CREATE TABLE temp (code VARCHAR, nutriscore INT)');
data.forEach(item => db.run('INSERT INTO temp (code, nutriscore) VALUES (?, ?)', [item.code, item.nutriscore]));
db.each('SELECT nutriscore, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM temp GROUP BY nutriscore', row => document.write(`число ${row.nutriscore} == ${row.cnt} раз(а) <br>`));
```

```html
<script src="https://lovasoa.github.io/sql.js/js/sql.js"></script>
```

:)

Comment: Плюс с меня за извращенство)))